# Order data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next code:

```js
export default function App() {
  function handleChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    const r = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")).map((i) => {
      if (i.color === value) {
        return {
          ...i,
          test: [{ t: 1, y: 5 }]
        };
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(r));
  }
  const cars = [
    {
      car: "bmw",
      price: 10,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      car: "audi",
      price: 55,
      color: "white"
    },
    {
      car: "opel",
      price: 45,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ];
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(cars));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>write in localstorage</p>
      <Select
        placeholder="colors"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Option value="red">red</Option>
        <Option value="blue">blue</Option>
        <Option value="blue">white</Option>
        <Option value="blue">black</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I  want, when i will select a value ant that value will be equall with `color` from the array, to add additional propriety inside that object that will fit the condition(`if (i.color === value) {`).
So at the end i want to get something like this:

```css
[
    {
      car: "bmw",
      price: 10,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      car: "audi",
      price: 55,
      color: "white"
    },
    {
      car: "opel",
      price: 45,
      color: "blue"
      test: [{t: 1, y: 5}, {t: 1, y: 5}, {t: 1, y: 5}] // length depends by how                many times i select somthing that fits the condition
]
    }
  ]
  
  //another example
  
  [
    {
      car: "bmw",
      price: 10,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      car: "audi",
      price: 55,
      color: "white"
      test: [{t: 1, y: 5}, {t: 1, y: 5}, {t: 1, y: 5}] // user clicked 3 times on white
    },
    {
      car: "opel",
      price: 45,
      color: "blue"
      
]
    }
  ]
```

**Question: How to get what i described? Now i get null if i select for the first time.**

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-euler-4ce8y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Probably do some regular debugging on your code first? If I run your linked code, and click the select, I immediately get `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `blue`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.` - fix bugs first, then see if your original problem still exists.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, i changed, the warning dissapered

Comment: open the real dev tools in your browser, and then look at your console output.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, i fixed the warning but the issue still

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, could you show a solution please?

Comment: @AskMen check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some corrections.

Check this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dirac-vjfoi

main fix is this

```
const r = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")).map((i) => {
  if (i.color === value) {
    return {
      ...i,
      test: i.test ? [...i.test, { t: 1, y: 5 }] : [{ t: 1, y: 5 }]
    };
  } else return { ...i };
});
```

When the color is equal to the selected one, if test exits, then add the extra object, else initialize a new array.

If not, just return the object.

Comment: your answer helpend me before and is related with this question, could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377199/add-data-in-a-specific-proprety-of-object

Comment: @AskMen sorry i was on vacations. i ll have a look at it later

Answer (score -1):

In the last part of the code, where you actually write the website, you have all of the last four options with the key of "blue". Try changing those to the normal colors. HTML is throwing an error. The problem that eslint has is because you do not make sure to consistently return something. You need to make sure to have the function always return. Try changing to this:

```js
(i) => {
      if (i.color === value) {
        return {
          ...i,
          test: [{ t: 1, y: 5 }]
        }
      } else {return i;} //this makes sure function always returns value
    }
```

Comment: i fixed the issue with colors, but do you have any solution?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I edited it with another change. (I can't comment yet because I only have 9 rep)